# How can I see a contact's date of birth?

Tags: wordpress, contacts, contact-view

How can I see a contact's date of birth?

I know it's entered because it's a mandatory field in the event sign-up form, but when I view the contact, I just see very limited data. How do I see ALL the contact's fields? This is using WP+CiviCrm (newest version 5.68.0).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot is a customized layout rather than the standard one.
The standard layout would show birth date, but one of 2 customizations on your site is hiding it:

1. You might be using the [Contact Layout Editor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor) extension. If so, you should edit the layout to include the "Demographics" section.
2. You might have disabled the panes in your Display Preferences. To fix it, go to **Administer -> Customize Data & Screens -> Display Preferences** in the menubar and ensure "Demographics" is enabled

[image: Display Preferences]

Comment: Thank you. I do not have that extension installed. I have enabled the Demographics section and I now see these fields - but to my dismay they are blank! The sign-up profile specifically has "Person: date of birth" and it's mandatory (gender, too), so I don't see how the data can be missing here.

Comment: Follow-up question: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/46130/event-registration-form-does-not-save-mandatory-contact-details-into-the-civi-co